# Inserting new row based on a certain cell value of another row

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have a sheet with thousands of entries and I need to insert a row if the Z column (also labeled as 'color series type') is equal to 'colorSeriesMaster'. This new row needs to go above the row that contains that value.

Before this gets marked as a duplicate question none of the others have helped me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub InsertRow()
Cells.Find(What:="colorSeriesMaster", After:=Range("Z1")).Activate
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert
End Sub
```

Comment: Where exactly do I put this? alt-F11?

Comment: Create a new module in Visual Basic and just copy the code into that. Does 'colourSeriesMaster' appear more than once in the data or is there only one instance (and thus only one row to add)?

Comment: It appears many times. Almost 1000 times. All in seperate rows but the same column. So if that cell includes 'colorSeriesMaster' then insert one row above that. Then repeat...

Comment: This worked but only for the first record that had 'colorSeriesMaster' in it. How do I make it repeat?